# apex:inputSecret pops up display: none in IE8 and 9

Tags: visualforce, internet-explorer

This issue only happens in IE8 and 9. It works fine on IE10 and 11 and other browsers.

I am having this piece of code:

```
<tr>
     <td class="tableLabel">Password</td>
     <td><apex:inputSecret value="{!newUser.password}" styleClass="password input100" html-placeholder="Password" onblur="validateCreateAccount('password');"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="tableLabel">Repeat Password</td>
    <td><apex:inputSecret value="{!newUser.confirmPassword}" styleClass="confirmPassword input100" html-placeholder="Confirm Password" onblur="validateCreateAccount('confirmPassword');"/></td>
</tr>
```

In IE8 and IE9, when you click on the input secret box, the cursor will disappear and disables you from editing it. When I looked at it in the developer tool, the inline style becomes display: none. I am so unsure why it has been brought. The two inputSecret boxes don't have any onclick event handlers. And display:none style is not there before clicking on it. Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe that `<apex:inputSecret>` is outputted as an <`input>` element which has very limited support on IE8 and IE9. See http://caniuse.com/#search=input. But you could try removing your styling (`password`, `confirmPassword`, `input100`) to see if there is something strange going on there.

Comment: @BarCotter Thank you for your suggestions. But I have searched the style classes before posting this thread and didn't see them in css code. Strange though.

Comment: I guess I kind of understand what is happening here. placeholder is not supported by IE9 and previous versions which probably caused this issue. I will try it tomorrow to confirm.